Probability: Starting with $\$200$, chance of winning $\$100$ by placing on black in Roulette?
Suppose we want to win $\$100$ playing Roulette by putting our chips on black, starting with $\$200$. That is: ending up with $\$300$.
If we place all our chips on black, then the chance of winning $\$200$ and losing $\$200$ are $49\%$ and $51\%$, respectively. That is, ending with $\$400$ and $0$, respectively.
Is there a way to calculate our chances of winning $\$100$ (that is, ending with $\$300$) however? Say, through splitting our bets, etc?

What type of roulette wheel are you using? One that has a single green 0, or one that has a green 0 and another green 00? In either case the probabilities of win/loss are not exactly 49%/51%.
Also, do you plan to stick to a single strategy, e.g. bet 50 each time until you have either 300 or 0 dollars, or do you wish to change your bet in response to previous wins/losses?

Once you have picked the strategy you will follow, this is a variant of the usual Gampler's Ruin problem.

If it were a fair wheel you could use expected value to say your chances are $2/3$ for any strategy that made sure you never go above $\$300$.  This is an upper bound, but since this wheel is close to fair we should be able to get close to this.  We generally want to minimize the amount bet because the bet is less than fair.
A natural strategy is to bet enough to get to $\$300$ if you can and bet all you have otherwise.  This one is easy to calculate because you can only be at $0, 100, 200, 300$.  We always bet $100$.  If we let $a$ be the probability of success if we have $200$ and $b$ be the probability of success if we have $100$ we have
$$a=.49+.51b\\b=.49a\\a=.49+.51\cdot.49a\\a=\frac {.49}{1-.49\cdot .51}\approx 0.6532$$
which is rather close to $2/3$
Another strategy is to use the classic doubling approach.  If we make our unit $25$ we can double three times before we run out of money.  We have to win four times through the strategy to get to $300$.  A lower bound is to insist we win the first four times though our doubling.  We win $25$ with probability $1-.51^3$ so we get to $300$ with probability $(1-.51^3)^4\approx 0.566$.  This is an underestimate because if we lose three in a row we still have some money and might still win.

Regarding the "doubling approach", I am not sure I understood it entirely. Is that betting $25$, then $50$, then $100$, then $200$? If so, we would win more than our desired $100$ should all four bets be successful. I am sure I misunderstood it...

That is correct but you don't have enough money to be the 200.  If you lose a bet you bet the next number.  If you win a bet you have won 25 on the series and start again at 25.

I see. So we bet $25$, and if we win, we bet $25$ again. Therefore, winning four times would win us our desired $100$. But suppose we bet $25$ and lose, then we bet $50$ the next time (from our pool of $175$), etc... although losing all bets, we could not bet $200$, but only $100$, as $300-(25+50+100+200)=-75$

Yes, that is correct.  If you don't need to bet whole dollars you could start with 13 1/3 and have enough to double four times, but then you would only win 13 1/3 per series.  I think the always bet 100 strategy will be very hard to beat

If you want to win \$100 and end up with \$300 there are many ways to do that.
If you bet one time \$100 you have a 49% chance.
Say you divide your money into 20 lots of \$10 and bet each lot one time only (no betting winnings) then you have only 1.2% chance of winning exactly \$300! You have to win exactly 15 times and lose 5 times.  (If you are on a single zero roulette wheel, your actual chance of winning exactly \$300 is 1.12%)
Probability =   $ (0.486)^{15}*(0.514)^5*\frac{20!}{15!5!} $
Here is a graph of probability vs number of wins

So the probability of winning exactly \$300 depends completely on the strategy you choose.
Let's go back to betting \$100 at a time.
Let’s suppose you gamble \$100 and win, you have \$300. If you lose that first bet, and gamble the other \$100 and win you’re back to \$200 so you can try one more time. Suppose you then lose, you once again bet the remaining \$100 and carry on. The final probability of winning \$300 on a single zero roulette wheel is about 65%.

The text assumes that if you have lots of 10 you will bet all of them, but you should stop if you ever hit 300.  You also could bet them all, win some, and then play some more to get to 300

@RossMillikan I understand that, that why I stipulated single bets, no re-betting winnings. I did the calculation for betting $100 with betting winnings, but for the $10 case I don't have time.
